# How to fix windows becomming unresponsive when two users are logged in?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have a strange behavior on my PC, which runs Windows 10 Pro where multiple users can log in.

When only Bob has logged in, then everything works fine for him. If after a reboot Alice logs in, everything works fine for her.

If Bob has logged in, and then they switch the user (Bob remains active in the background) and  Alice log in, Alice will now experience issues with Windows as in: It will not really login but remain in a limbo state.

One symptom of the limbo state is: I can hover with the mouse over the start start menu, but I cannot click it. It only shows the hour glass. Yet it can run for minutes and it will never go away.

If I press the Windows key, nothing happens. I can start application through the Task Manager via File > Run Task. That way I got the `chrome` instance to open in which I am now writing this question. Alt Tabbing does not work. No windows shortcut besides Ctrl + Alt + Delete works. (E.g. Win + R, or Win + E do not yield any action.)

I can interact with my system via the task manager, yet logging everybody out and logging in as one user does not work. One has to reboot and only log in as one specific user for the issue to go away making multi-user-usage unusable.

The only workaround I currently see is: reboot and only log in as either Bob or Alice. If users want to switch, reboot.

---

Bob is admin account. Alice is normal user. Bob is linked to an outlook account, Alice is not.

---

I let Bob idle for 15 minutes. Then suddenly, the log in process completed. No error message was shown.

Comment: How much memory does this system have? How much free space on your hard drive? What programs are starting up for each user session? Your standard Windows computer can handle one active session and several locked sessions without issue, so this is definitely something going not correctly.

Comment: @music2myear 250GB free space  on a 500GB on free M2 SSD on `C:\`, 32 GB RAM.

Comment: Ok, next you need to look at logs and running processes. If you aren't running out of RAM, then you've probably got some logon process that's either hung, or doesn't like running on two accounts simultaneously.

Comment: @music2myear Where can I find these logs?

Comment: @music2myear RAM usage idles around 6GB of my 32 GB, so nothing fancy going on there.

Comment: Event Viewer, to start with.

Comment: You probably don't intend this, but you're making an error in your title: You don't need to find out how to fix the computer hanging or going slowly when the second user logs in, you need to find out WHY the computer freeze or runs slowly when a second user logs in. Knowing why will generally lead toward the solution, but you cannot actually solve the problem unless you know the why. So, you need to focus first on diagnosis, and allow resolution to follow later.